# JS: Rebound "this" in contextless function call

Tags: javascript, function, function-binding

The function `doSomethingElse` in this example fails to execute since its `this` has been rebound to `window` or `global` (if in Node) due to a contextless call inside `app.populateDatabase`.

Is there any way to avoid this without referencing `app` inside every function?

`loadDatabase` function executes a callback according to a logic statement, if an imaginary database didn't exist, it populates it after loading, then the `populateDatabase` executes the callback it has been provided.

I cannot rebind the `onLoaded` argument to `app` since I don't know where it comes from, and the bind/apply/call abstraction overuse creates quite a mess.

```
var app = {};
app.loadDatabase = function(onLoaded) {

    // If database already exists, only run a callback
    var callback = onLoaded;

    // If database doesn't exists, populate it, then run a callback.
    if (!databaseExists) {
        callback = this.populateDatabase.bind(this, onLoaded);
    }

    this.database = new sqlite.Database("file.db", function(error) {
        if (error) { ... }

        callback();
    })

}

app.populateDatabase = function(onPopulated) {

    // Contextless call here. <--------
    onPopulated();
}

app.doSomethingElse = function() {

    // this != app due to contextless call.
    this.somethingElse();
}

app.run = function() {

    // Load the database, then do something else.
    this.loadDatabase(this.doSomethingElse);
}

app.run();
```

Comment: Use ES6 arrow functions then (which don't have a `this` of their own).

Comment: @connexo How would that help exactly? I'm using `this` to reference the `app` without actually naming it.

Comment: It means that the function will have the `this` that was available right outside the call.

Comment: The other option is to add `.bind(app)` to any function definition inside which you expect `this` to always point to `app`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `this.loadDatabase(this.doSomethingElse);`
  with `this.loadDatabase(() => this.doSomethingElse());`. This way you create a new arrow function but then `doSomethingElse` is called with the right `this` context.

You could also do `.bind` but I recommend the arrow function. Here with `bind`: `this.loadDatabase(this.doSomethingElse.bind(this))`

---

In general consider to move to promises & maybe async functions. Then do this:

```
this.loadDatabase().then(() => this.doSomethingElse());
```

or better with an async function:

```
await this.loadDatabase();
this.doSomethingElse();
```

Comment: In that case, the arrow function should return the function's value instead of the function itself.

`this.loadDatabase(() => this.doSomethingElse)`: passed parameter is an arrow function that returns a reference to `doSomethingElse`.

`this.loadDatabase(() => this.doSomethingElse())`: passed parameter is an arrow function that calls `doSomethingElse` and returns the returned value.

Comment: yep. sorry, I corrected it. Feel free to edit in such cases ;)